# Detect if the directory is modified in java

Tags: java, windows, validation, directory

I have a requirement that *I need to validate the modification of directory that I used to create by my java application.*

A user can modify a directory by creating a file and deleting a file or modify as well so I want to just validate that the particular directory is modified.

**My solution: I need to have a hash that contain the last modified time and each time I have to match the last modified time of directory by my hash.**

But my techies have objection that there are many tricks and library so that user can modify its last modified time.

So tell me please alternate to it.

Comment: Check out Java 7's `WatchService`.

Answer (score 1):

use java 7 watch service api

```
for (;;) {

    WatchKey key;
    try {
        key = watcher.take();
    } catch (InterruptedException x) {
        return;
    }

    for (WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {
        WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();

        if (kind == OVERFLOW) {
            continue;
        }

        WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>)event;
        Path filename = ev.context();
       try {
            Path child = dir.resolve(filename);
            if (!Files.probeContentType(child).equals("text/plain")) {
                System.err.format("New file '%s'" +
                    " is not a plain text file.%n", filename);
                continue;
            }
        } catch (IOException x) {
            System.err.println(x);
            continue;
        }

        System.out.format("Emailing file %s%n", filename);
     }

    boolean valid = key.reset();
    if (!valid) {
        break;
    }
}
```